# Use text file lines as variables in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, stylesheet

I'm looing to get lines from a text file available as variables in my stylesheet.

So the TXT file holds lines like:

```
One
Two
Three
```

.

Ultimate goal is to use the XSLT to create an HTML list of options  with each line of the text file as an .

Can anybody give me some directions please? Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? If not, can you at least wrap the contents of the text file in XML tags?

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:variable name="text-lines" 
  select="tokenize(unparsed-text('input.txt'), '\r?\n')"/>
```